# Symfony2 Sonata deleteUser in hard delete

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sql-delete

I have some issues to delete a User using sonata user-bundle. I have createdAt and updatedAt fields in my entity but no deletedAt. I don't want to add one in my entity but hard delete the entity because of duplicated uniq email while imports.

My code looks like :

```
$userManager      = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$duplicatedEntity = $entityRepository->findOneBy(array('email' => $newUser->getEmail()));

if( $duplicatedEntity !== null ){
    $userManager->deleteUser($duplicatedEntity);
}
```

Problem is that nothing happend when it go through the `deleteUser` . I log a file when it passes by it, so I'm sure that it goes through ...